# Promises with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got this bit of code right now, where I get all the templates I need for a page.

Problem is that this way the ajax requests doesn't finish in the same order every time I load the page.

Is there a way to use promises or something else so that the load order always stays the same?
Thanks.

```
var loadTemplates = function (templatesObject) {
    $.each(templatesObject.template, function (index, template) {
        template.callback = template.callback || $.noop;

        $.ajax({
            url: template.url,
            success: function(html) {
                var compiledHtml = Handlebars.compile(html);
                var output = compiledHtml(template.data);
                $(template.target).append(output);
                template.callback();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Edit: This is how my object looks like, with varying amounts of templates, just 2 in this instance.

**templatesObject**

```
var templates = {
    template: [
        {
            url: 'firsturl',
            target: '#page-content'
        },
        {
            url: 'myurl',
            target: '#page-content',
            data: data,
            callback: awesomefunction
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the fact that $.ajax returns a promise, use $.map instead of $.each, and use $.when to wait for all the ajax to complete, and do what you do in the success callback in the $.when().then callback ...

```
var loadTemplates = function (templatesObject) {
    $.when.apply($, $.map(templatesObject.template, function (index, template) {
        template.callback = template.callback || $.noop;
        return $.ajax({
            url: template.url,
        }).then(function(html) {
            return {html: html, template: template};
        });
    })).then(function() {
        $.each(arguments, function(index, result) {
            var compiledHtml = Handlebars.compile(result.html);
            var output = compiledHtml(result.template.data);
            $(result.template.target).append(output);
            result.template.callback();
        })
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I console log the template in the when I get 0 instead of the template object.
I added an example of what my object looks like if it is of any help. Thanks

Comment: each argument is an array, data is the first element of that array. Also `arguments` is array like object

Comment: When I switched around the position of `index` and `template` in the `when`, I got the template data when console logging the template.
But I am not able to find the template data in the `then` portion, not in `arguments`, `index` or `html`

Comment: I think I fixed it :p